# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageurl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I looked all over the internet and still couldn't find the right answer. I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageurl' of undefined'. React is rendering first before componentDidMount or anything else I have tried.

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProductImageBackground } from '../../Redux/actions';

class ProductCategoryPage extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        fetchProductImageBackground();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="productCategoryPage" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.backgroundImages[0].imageurl})`}}>
                <div className="productCategoryPage__section">
                    <p className="productCategoryPage__section-type">product category</p>
                    <h1 className="productCategoryPage__section-title">category</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="productCategoryPage">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        backgroundImages:state.productCategoryBackgroundImage
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ProductCategoryPage);
```

Comment: Did you try logging the backgroundImages prop? It seems that this array doesn’t hold any value.

Comment: Is it not possible to load data into the array when it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
if (!this.props.backgroundImages) return null;
```

at the beginning of your render() method. Once the data is in place, your component gets rendered again.

How does `fetchProductImageBackground()` look like? In case it's synchronous, you could also call it during Redux store initialization. Otherwise, you'd need to handle the "we're waiting for data" case anyway.